# Is every normal subgroup of $G$ of this form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G = H \times K$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $L$ is a normal subgroup
> of $K$, show that $N \times L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Is every normal subgroup of $G$ of
> this form?

**My attempt:**

> Let $G = H \times K$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $L$ is a normal subgroup
> of $K$, show that $N \times L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Since $e\in N$ and $e\in L$, then $(e,e)\in N\times L$. If $(n_1,l_1),(n_2,l_2) \in N\times L$, then $(n_1,l_1)(n_2,l_2)=(n_1n_2,l_1l_2)\in N\times L$. Also, if $n\in N$, then $n^{-1}\in N$ and if $l\in L$, then $l^{-1}\in L$, so $(n,l)(n^{-1},l^{-1})=(nn^{-1},ll^{-1})=(e,e)$. Thus $N\times L$ has inverses and therefore, $N\times L \leq G$.

For normality, if $(h,k)$ is an element of $G$ and $(n,l)\in N\times L$, then $(h^{-1},k^{-1})(n,l)(h,k)=(h^{-1}nh,k^{-1}lk)$. Since $N$ is normal in $H$ and $L$ is normal in $K$, we have $h^{-1}nh\in N$ and $k^{-1}lk\in L$, so $(h^{-1}nh,k^{-1}lk) \in N\times L $ and therefore $N\times L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

> Is every normal subgroup of $G$ of this form?

In this part, my intuition says yes, but I don't know how to formalize this, could you help me to formalize the answer, either positive or negative?

Comment: No, consider $C_2\times C_2$

Comment: Yes if you allow $L$ to be trivial though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider for example the group $G=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. It has the (normal) subgroup $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ which is not of the desired form. However under certain conditions it is true, for example when $H,K$ are finite of coprime order.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me, if you consider $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ as a normal subgroup of $G$. You are taking $\{0,1\}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which is normal and would be fulfilling the requirements. Or am I missing the obvious?

Comment: In this example $H=\Bbb Z_2,K=\Bbb Z_2$. Go through the different subgroups of $H,K$ and look at their product inside $G$. You will see that you won't get $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. For example $\Bbb Z_2\times 0$ doesn't contain $(1,1)$

Comment: Oh now I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No.  For any abelian group $G$, you can consider the diagonal subgroup of $G\times G$, given by $\Delta=\{(g,g)|g\in G\}$.  $\Delta\not\cong H\times L$ for any nontrivial $H,L\lt G$.